# A trick to have line of paragraph go from bottom up and not from top down

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I've got this silly little idea of zero practical use that I'd like to know how to put to practice using HTML. Ordinarily, a body of text is wrapped, spanning multiple lines that are laid out one after another from the top of the enclosing container down. Like in this blockquote:

> Anyone familiar with caching algorithms will groan when they read the description of the
>
> "sampling" LRU. First, LRU isn't that great--it is a *lot* better than nothing and having a suitably
>
> large cache tends to cover up cache eviction problems, but LRU is still susceptible to a number
>
> of problems. The pseudo-LRU redis used to have is appropriate for very high-speed caches (it's
>
> essentially a 5-way associative cache), but is so very not appropriate when going out to disk,
>
> where the access latency is horrible.

If on the other hand I wanted to have the lines go from the bottom of the enclosing container up, like in *this* blockquote, what'd be my options?

> where the access latency is horrible.
>
> essentially a 5-way associative cache), but is so very not appropriate when going out to disk,
>
> of problems. The pseudo-LRU redis used to have is appropriate for very high-speed caches (it's
>
> large cache tends to cover up cache eviction problems, but LRU is still susceptible to a number
>
> "sampling" LRU. First, LRU isn't that great--it is a *lot* better than nothing and having a suitably
>
> Anyone familiar with caching algorithms will groan when they read the description of the

Right from the get-go it's clear HTML+CSS has no mechanism for achieving this. (Right?) So JS seems to be a way to go, but since the beginning and end of the line is determined by the layouting engine, I can't just randomly split the text in chunks, call them lines, reverse them and lay them out in that order. **Is there a way to tap to the layouting engine to get the line beginnings and ends?**

I don't expect there's a practical *or* hacky way to do this and retain things like `img`s floated in to still work, or dynamic `font-size` changes / responsive layout being somehow possible. But the idea of this is too amusing to me, so I'd like to know how far I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's pretty straight forward if I understood you well.

You'd have to have HTML structure like this

```
<div class="text-cont">
   <p> Some line </p>
   <p> Some line </p>
</div>
```

so paragraph defines a line. I used jquery for simplicity so before you can start using my script you have to have

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   ></script>
```

in `<head>` section of your html.

Now js code is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.text-cont').click(function(){
        var newElementOrder = $('.text-cont').children().toArray().reverse();
    $('.text-cont').empty();
    for(var i=0;i<newElementOrder.length;i++){
      $('.text-cont').append(newElementOrder[i]);
    }
  });

});
```

Here is a fiddle of it working https://jsfiddle.net/5nhr5L1s/

Comment: But this way you define where the lines break by wrapping them in `p`s. Do you think the browser layout engine could be let be in charge of the wrapping, but not the positioning, so the lines are split by the browser, but reversed before rendering?

Comment: nope, you must define lines clearly with some element, that what you're aiming at is not possible

Comment: Turns out you indeed can't get any useful layout info out of the browser. I had some hope for the `Range` API and `canvas` text measurement, but neither gets there.